# Arduino как посредник между сенсором и PC. Каша вместо данных по USB

Tags: c++, arduino, serial, avr

У меня есть некий сенсор отправляющий байты данных со скоростью 57600 Бодов в секунду. Как посредник я использовал Arduino. Он принимает данные от сенсора ищет там стартовый сигнал (0xAA 0xAA) принимает первый байт как длину послед-х данных принимает данные в массив, вычисляет checksum? и если все ок, пересылает данные на компьютер по USB. 
Но на PC приходит чушь!
Для проверки я подключил на RX0 другой Arduino, и он принимает все как надо, вся инфа приходит той какой должна быть (данные смотрю на LCD экране).

Однако, если я присылаю какое-нибудь одно число каждый раз вместо принятых данных, то оно приходит на ура! т.е. если я посылаю букву "а" то на комп. и на второй Arduino приходит цифра "97". 
В программе на Arduino я использовал родные команды AVR для отправки и принятия по USART плюс циклический буффер. Скорость принятия 57600, отправки 115200 (пробовал и 57600 на отправку, все одно).

Вот код Arduino-посредника:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);
#define BuffSize 128
#define BuffMask (BuffSize-1)
#define inputPin 5
#define pulseTimeLimit 17

uint64_t message;
boolean startInputParser = false;
boolean startSignal = false;
boolean firstByte = true;


volatile uint8_t dataLen;
volatile int inputBytes = 0;
volatile uint8_t dataInput[10];
uint8_t startSignalCmpr[2];
int a;
uint8_t rx_data = 0;
volatile uint8_t rx_flag = 0;
volatile uint8_t rbuffer[BuffSize];
uint8_t indexHead;
uint8_t indexTail;

void UARTInit(void)
{
    UBRR2H = 0;
    UBRR2L = pulseTimeLimit; //17 baud rate 57600 //103 baud rate 9600
    UCSR2B = (1 << RXEN2) | (1 << TXEN2) | (1 << RXCIE2);
    UCSR2C = (1 << UCSZ21) | (1 << UCSZ20); //8 bit, 1 stop bit //URSEL(write enabled) is not used in atmega2560

    UBRR0H = 0;
    UBRR0L = 8; //8 - 115200
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00); //8 bit, 1 stop bit //URSEL(write enabled) is not used in atmega2560    
}
void UARTSend(uint8_t data) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = data;
}

//idle until complete byte is received
unsigned char UARTGet()
{
    while (!rx_flag);
    rx_flag = 0;
    return rx_data;
}

int bytesAvailable()
{
    if (indexHead == indexTail)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        return (indexHead - indexTail)&BuffMask; //mask's needed if head started over beginning
    }
}

//Read one byte at a time
uint8_t readPerByte()
{

    if (indexHead == indexTail)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    uint8_t readByte = rbuffer[indexTail++];
    indexTail &= BuffMask; //if reached end of array buffer[] reset to "0" indexHead    
    return readByte;
}

//aka serial.peek()
uint8_t glancePerByte()
{
    if (indexHead == indexTail)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    uint8_t readByte = rbuffer[indexTail];
    return readByte;
}

//send data payload to PC and erase dataInput[] 
void inputParser()
{
    if (!startInputParser)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputBytes; i++)
    {
        UARTSend(dataInput[i]);
        dataInput[i] = 0;
    }

    startInputParser = false;
}


void prtlParser()
{
    if (!startSignal || startInputParser || !bytesAvailable())
        return;
    //first byte is lenght of data payload
    if (firstByte)
    {
        dataLen = readPerByte();
        if (dataLen > 10) //dataLen is always less than 10
            return;

        firstByte = false;
        inputBytes = 0;
        return;
    }

    else if (inputBytes != dataLen)
    {
        dataInput[inputBytes++] = readPerByte();
        return;
    }

    int checkSumRecvd;
    uint32_t dataSum;

    checkSumRecvd = readPerByte();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputBytes; i++)
    {
        dataSum += dataInput[i];
    }

    uint8_t calcdChecksum;
    calcdChecksum ^= dataSum & 0xFF;
    calcdChecksum = ~calcdChecksum;

    startSignal = 0;
    firstByte = true;
    if (checkSumRecvd == calcdChecksum) // invert first, then pick lowest byte
    {
        startInputParser = true;
        dataSum = 0;
    }
}

void startSigSeek()
{
    startSignalCmpr[0] = readPerByte();

    if (startSignalCmpr[0] != 170)
    {
        startSignalCmpr[0] = readPerByte();
        return;
    }

    if (startSignalCmpr[0] == 170)
    {
        startSignalCmpr[1] = readPerByte();

        if (startSignalCmpr[0] = startSignalCmpr[1])
        {

            startSignal = true;
        }
        startSignalCmpr[0] = 0;
        startSignalCmpr[1] = 0;
    }
}

void setup()
{
    sei();
    UARTInit();
}

void loop()
{
    if (bytesAvailable() > 0)
    {
        if (!startSignal)
        {


            startSigSeek();

        }

        //if startSignal is true calculate checksum
        if (!startInputParser)
        {
            prtlParser();
        }

        if (startInputParser)
        {
            inputParser();
        }

    }
}

ISR(USART2_RX_vect)
{
    rbuffer[indexHead++] = UDR2;
    indexHead &= BuffMask;
    rx_flag = 1;
}
```

Вот код читающий USB порт на PC:
(код не мой, я взял чужой сэмпл, и изменил его чтобы видить raw data а не ASCII буквы)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
char buf[128];
char* pbuf = buf;
int counter = 0;

HANDLE hCom, hEvent;
DWORD bytesRead, bWritten;

BOOL fSuccess;
HANDLE hThread;
DWORD dwParam, dwThreadId;

VOID WINAPI ThreadProc(PVOID* dummy) {
    printf("Ждите данные из порта СОМ3...\n");
    while (true) {
        ReadFile(hCom, pbuf, 1, &bytesRead, NULL);
        if (bytesRead>0)
        {
            //WriteFile(hCom, pbuf++, 1, &bWritten, NULL);
            counter++;
            if (counter == 10) {
                SetEvent(hEvent);
                buf[counter] = '\0';
                counter = 0;
                pbuf = buf;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    LPCWSTR comPort = L"\\\\.\\COM3";
    //char* pcComPort = "COM4";
    DCB dcb;
    FILE* fout;
    hCom = CreateFile(comPort, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Ошибка открытия COM3!\n");
        while (!_kbhit());
        return 1;
    }
    GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_57600;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &dcb);
    if (!fSuccess) {
        printf("Попытка вызвать SetCommState провалилась!\n");
        while (!_kbhit());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("COM порт %s успешно сконфигурирован\n", comPort);
    GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);
    printf("Скорость порта %s равна %d\n", comPort, dcb.BaudRate);

    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadProc,
        &dwParam, 0, &dwThreadId);
    //if ((fout = fopen("C:\\test", "a+")) == NULL)

        errno_t errorCode;
    if ((errorCode = fopen_s(&fout, "G:\\test.txt", "a+")) != 0) // "a+" or "w"
    {
        printf("Не могу создать файл G:\\test.txt");
        while (!_kbhit());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Нажмите клавишу для выхода...\n");
    do {
        WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
        int i = 0;
        //printf("%s\n", buf);

        while (buf[i])
        { 
        printf("%u\n", buf[i]);
        fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), 10, fout);
        i++;
        }

    } while (!_kbhit());
    fclose(fout);
    CloseHandle(hCom);
    return 0;
}
```

Вот пример данных принимаемых на PC: 
(Каждая строчка это один байт отправленной инфы, следовательно она не может содержать число больше 255)

```
4294967286
4294967295
14
45
78
35
4294967266
5
40
4294967280
4294967203
4294967233
40
4294967168
4294967247
4294967168
4294967180
4294967203
40
4294967255
40
4294967265
40
40
4294967240
40
4294967180
4294967233
4294967279
4294967236
4294967232
102
101
4294967206
44
4294967289
103
40
40
33
35
36
4294967242
4294967204
4294967249
4294967284
99
40
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять почему приходит каша если посылать реальные байты, и почему приходит нормально если присылать одно и то же число но с той же частотой?

Comment: Новые данные: Оказывается что, все числа больше 127-и приходят в такой непонятной форме `4294967289` где сама цифра является тремя последними цифрами минус 40 '289 - 40 = 249'. Что это может значить представления не имею, однако число 127 это `01111111` а все числа больше него уже имеют `1` в самом верхнем бите тоесть начиная с 128 это `10000000` и так далее. Что за проблема с этим первым битом? Забыл добавить что в описании UART сенсора написано что там "один стартовый бит" а в винде стоит "один стоповый". Но у передачи же всегда стоят "один стартовый" и "один стоповый" биты... разве нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4294967286 - это 0xFFFFFFF6. Этого уже достаточно, что бы понять.

А теперь длинное объяснение. Буффер buf  у Вас имеет тип char, И Вы думаете, что там unsigned char. А там signed char. Соответственно, когда этот char пытаетесь распечатать как unsigned int, оно вначале делает расширение, а потом кастует.

То есть, в переменой храниться 0xF6 (246). При его расширении до 4 байт, старшие биты заполняются единицами (это единицы знака). И получается 0xFFFFFFF6.

Как по мне, так самый простой способ пофиксить - это просто сделать буфер беззнаковым.

```
unsigned char buf[128];
unsigned char* pbuf = buf;
```

> проблема с этим первым битом?

это знаковый бит:)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я как-то подумал  изменить тип этой переменной в другом сэмпле, но в этом,  почему-то, забыл. Все отлично заработало, еще раз благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

В функции ThreadProc у вас происходит полная фигня. ReadFile всегда считывает один байт в pbuf, pbuf всегда равен buf, при этом поток-потребитель уведомляется только тогда, когда в pbuf записано 10 раз по байту, т.е. по сути 9 из них игнорируются. В оставшихся позициях buf остается мусор, который выводится.

Нужно на каждой итерации делать ++pbuf, но всё еще остаются проблемы: многопоточной синхронизации можно сказать что нет. В buf[10] записывает 0 только после того, как потребитель получил уведомление. Ничего не мешает ему считать буфер до того, как  туда записан 0 (спасает только то, что этот 0 никто не перезаписывает на самом деле). При этом поток-поставщик может записывать данные в буфер быстрее, чем потребитель будет их считывать, т.е. буфер будет перезаписан до того, потребитель его считает.

Comment: Благодарю ВАС, вы тоже были правы, я просто использовал другой сэмпл и подправил char на unsigned char. Все заработало. Вот почему не люблю изменять готовые сэмплы, но с win кодом приходится так как не опытен.